# How to save UI state of a QT application?

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have a software with different components ( button, slider, ...). I want to save all components state (clicked, slider value, ..).

I heard there is **QSettings** which can save state. But in my software, i can't know which components exists because i create them "randomly" at runtime.

Looking for a solution to be able to save the whole ui state. Thanks.

**EDIT :**

My question wasn't clear so i will explain a bit futher, i don't need to save state between 2 sessions of the application, i just need to save state for later without restarting the software. I can get the list of ui components using findChildren for exemple.

Comment: If you create them "randomly" there is no state you should save. No?

Comment: @vahancho Let me explain, for exemple my software will create 2 checkbox, when i click the button "save", i want that my software save the checked state of this 2 textbox.Then i check and uncheck the checbox randomly... Then, when i click "load", it will change the checked state of the checkbox to the initial one.

Comment: But you said `"...i can't know which components exists..."`, so if you save the state of checkboxes and on next session you will not have them, how are you going to restore the sate?

Comment: @vahancho Sorry for being unclear, i edited the post.

Comment: Thanks. I think you also should define what "state" means. For a check box it can be check state, for line edit - text, etc. In general you can loop over all existing widgets and serialize their properties into a file using `QSettings` or your custom format (JSON, YML etc.)

Comment: @vahancho I will do as you said with QSettings, and loop over all widget. Thanks

Comment: implement model, attach model to widgets with `QWidgetMapper` and save model data